# How to set default fragment in android?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have tried several ways to set the default fragment as the 1st list item when app open's for the first time and last opened fragment when the app is not opened for the first time. But both scenarios are not working. Please help.

```
  mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int stupid, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            Strpath = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();
            source_id = Integer.parseInt(description);
            // Starting single contact activity
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString(TAG_NAME,name);
            data.putString(TAG_SOURCES, Strpath);
            Fragment fragment = new SingleContactActivity();
            fragment.setArguments(data);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    });
new GetContacts().execute();
```

FMI, I didnt use switch case in my program. I have tried

```
mDrawerList.setSelection(0);
```

---

Here is my array list adapter

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, navDrawerItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_SOURCES,
                TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
```

---

navDrawerItem , the item in the navdrawer is retrieve from MySQL

```
 try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_IPTV);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_SOURCES);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_PACKAGE);



                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_SOURCES, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PACKAGE, address);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    navDrawerItems.add(contact);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Did you try to put on SharedPreferences?

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry do you have any example how do I apply sharedPreferences?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: You can save the name of the fragment, and after recovery from shared preferences and select the fragment by the last name saved.

Comment: SharedPreferences are persisted in disk. Your bundle is destroyed after `onStop()`

Comment: Is SingleContactActivity your fragment?

Comment: I think this cannot work for me.. i have only 1 fragment but each of the item in listview press will bring different parameter ... the problem is i want the app can start with bring the first parameter to the fragment and run the fragment.

Comment: yes SingleContactActivity is my fragment ,VVB

Comment: The solution that i found from google is using switch case position, but i don't even have a switch case .. I just catch the item click listener to bring the parameter to the fragment and run

Comment: @VemonTey, if you want to change the display order of the list in the drawer,  you should change how you create that listadapter and the data it backs.  Post that code, then someone may help you achieve different ordering based on stored data (sharedprefs).

Comment: and now, post how you create `navDrawerItems` ( backing data)

Comment: I added the code that how i create my listadapter

Comment: I wanted to insert GetContacts() class code at the question but stackoverflow not allow ... since there is too much of code in the question

Comment: Ok done added how i create the navdrawer

Comment: Who can help me out ! I need the solution !!